# IPod touch 4th generation, USB connector is broken and password is lost - how to reactivate?

Tags: ipod

The USB connector of my iPod was broken some time ago. I was not able to connect the device to a computer or to charge it. Now - a few month later - an iPod repair store told me that it is not possible to repair the USB connector because it has a fixed connection to the mainboard. But they were able to make some pins working again. Now I can charge the device, but a connection to iTunes is not possible.

Now the problem is that I do not remember the unlock password. I tried some of my most commonly used, but after a few failures the iPod gives me only one PIN try and then locks the device for ten minutes. Resetting with iTunes is not possible because of the missing physical connection. Is there a way To make the iPod work again? There is no important data on it that has to be saved.

Comment: Guessing the pin or repairing the data lane functionality of the dock connector / main board are the only two avenues to erase all settings on the device.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot reset a PIN without iTunes.

The last thing that you could try is going to Genius Bar and hope that they can help.  Apple Stores have been known to completely replace broken devices, in some cases even if they aren't under warranty.